# Title and Category side by side

Tags: php, search, autocomplete

I want to see Title name and Category name in same line (**)
What am i missing?

```
if ( $stmt->rowCount()>0 ) {

    while($recResult = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $json_row["id"] = $recResult['Url'];
        $json_row["value"] = $recResult['Title'];
(**)    $json_row["label"] = $recResult['Title']; $json_row["value"] = $recResult['Category'];
        array_push($sugg_json, $json_row);
    }

} else {
```

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't really clear, how do you want to "view" them "side by side"? When you output them? Or when you build the array?
In either case you need to concatenate the strings, something like:

```
$json_row["label"] = $recResult['Title'] . $recResult['Category'];
```

Comment: This also works, but no space between Title and Category.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With your solution:

```
if ( $stmt->rowCount()>0 ) {

    while($recResult = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $json_row["id"] = $recResult['Url'];
        $json_row["value"] = $recResult['Title'];
(**)    $json_row["label"] = $recResult['Title']; $json_row["value"] = $recResult['Category'];
        array_push($sugg_json, $json_row);
    }

} else {
```

You have `;` in the middle of your line. This will end that section and process it.  That's what `;` in PHP, and many other programming languages, does.  It's called [Instruction Separation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)
I would assume you're looking to concatenate your strings, like so

```
if ( $stmt->rowCount()>0 ) {

    while($recResult = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $json_row["id"] = $recResult['Url'];
        $json_row["value"] = $recResult['Title'];
(**)    $json_row["label"] = $recResult['Title'] . " " . $recResult['Category'];
        array_push($sugg_json, $json_row);
    }

} else {
```

See [String Operations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) for more information.

Comment: Be sure to mark this as answered if you're satisfied.

Comment: I think you just click on a checkmark beside the answer.